Set NuGet tags at build time using reflection
I've got an application that has hundreds of plugins available as Nuget packages in a private repo.
The application's "Plugin Search" feature relies (in part) on embedding some metadata about each plugin's respective features in the package's <Tags> field.
My goal is to automatically populate each package's <Tags> at build time, based on reflecting over the types defined in the package's project.
Has anyone accomplished this trick of programmatically editing the nuget package properties?
I'm using sdk-style projects, dotnet 8, vs2022

This doesn't seem to have nothing to do with Roslyn. What have you tried and how did it fail?

@PauloMorgado I suspect one possible approach may be to use a roslyn analyzer with code fix to edit the '' property in the .csproj but I don't know enough about that toolset to know if it's viable.
I've been successful in extracting the metadata I need via reflection (by passing the compiled dll to an executable AfterBuild), but i've not found a good way to pass this metadata to the dotnet pack stage

I don't think Roslyn analizers can do that. You'd need a Visual Studio extension for that.

You can create a MSBuild task for that.
